# how to make wxpython password textctrl show chars?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

With wxPython a password field could be created as:

`wx.TextCtrl(frm, -1, '', style=wx.TE_PASSWORD )`

I'm wondering if there is a way to dynamically change this password field into a normal textctrl, such that user could see what the password is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its not possible to change the style flag after creating the control.

You can either destroy the control and create a new one without the password flag, or maintain two side by side in a sizer, with one always hidden. When you want to switch you can copy the text into the other text control, Hide one and Show the other then call Layout on the sizer.

```
import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        panel= wx.Panel(self)
        self.password_shown= False

        sizer= wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.password_sizer= wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.text_password= wx.TextCtrl(panel,style=wx.TE_PASSWORD)
        self.password_sizer.Add(self.text_password,0,wx.ALL,5)
        self.text_no_password= wx.TextCtrl(panel)
        self.text_no_password.Hide()
        self.password_sizer.Add(self.text_no_password,0,wx.ALL,5)
        sizer.Add(self.password_sizer)
        self.button= wx.Button(panel,-1,"Toggle Password")
        sizer.Add(self.button,0,wx.ALL,5)
        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnButton)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.Show()

    def OnButton(self,event):
        self.text_password.Show(self.password_shown)
        self.text_no_password.Show(not self.password_shown)
        if not self.password_shown:
            self.text_no_password.SetValue(self.text_password.GetValue())
            self.text_no_password.SetFocus()
        else:
            self.text_password.SetValue(self.text_no_password.GetValue())
            self.text_password.SetFocus()
        self.text_password.GetParent().Layout()
        self.password_shown= not self.password_shown


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app= wx.App(0)
    Frame(None)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of a way to dynamically change the style flags on the text control widget after creation. Some widgets allow this sort of thing on some OSes and some do not. You could just create two text controls with the second one in normal mode and hide it. Then when you want to toggle, you grab the password-protected version's value and hide it, give the value to the normal one and show it. You'll probably need to call Layout() at the end as well.

Answer (score -1):

then it would not be a password entry, but you can use style=wx.TE_MULTILINE or TE_RICH. if that is what you are asking.

Hope this helps