# wxPython "show password" eye-button

Tags: python, wxpython

```
pass_txt = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_PASSWORD | wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
```

I am using this to create a password box, and it shows black dots during insert to hide the password. It also shows a small arrow up if the CapsLock is active.

What I need is to add something like a small eye inside the box, that show the password when pressed. How can I do it?

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836062/how-to-make-wxpython-password-textctrl-show-chars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit of fun, so here goes as a `Dialog`:

```
import wx

class LoginDialog(wx.Dialog):
    """
    Login dialog
    """
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, None, title="Login")
        self.logged_in = False
        self.password_shown= False

        self.username = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1)     
        self.hidden_password = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, style=wx.TE_PASSWORD)
        self.visible_password = wx.TextCtrl(self)
        self.visible_password.Hide()
        self.lock = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, wx.Bitmap('lock.png'))
        self.login = wx.Button(self, -1, "Login")

        self.password_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.password_sizer.Add(self.hidden_password, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.password_sizer.Add(self.visible_password, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.password_sizer.Add(self.lock, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        mainsizer= wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        mainsizer.Add(self.username, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        mainsizer.Add(self.password_sizer)
        mainsizer.Add(self.login, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.lock.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnToggle)
        self.login.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnLogin)

        self.username.SetToolTip("Username")
        self.hidden_password.SetToolTip("Input password")
        self.visible_password.SetToolTip("Input password")
        self.lock.SetToolTip("Lock/Unlock password\nFor test purposes the password is\npassword1")

        self.SetSizer(mainsizer)

    def OnToggle(self, event):
        self.hidden_password.Show(self.password_shown)
        self.visible_password.Show(not self.password_shown)
        if not self.password_shown:
            self.visible_password.SetValue(self.hidden_password.GetValue())
            self.visible_password.SetFocus()
        else:
            self.hidden_password.SetValue(self.visible_password.GetValue())
            self.hidden_password.SetFocus()
        self.hidden_password.GetParent().Layout()
        self.password_shown = not self.password_shown

    def OnLogin(self, event):
        '''
        Perform your username/password vetting here
        or return the username/password pair for processing
        '''
        stupid_password1 = "password1"
        user_password1 = self.hidden_password.GetValue()
        if user_password1 == stupid_password1:
            self.logged_in = True
            self.Close()
        else:
            wx.MessageBox('Login failed', 'Error', wx.OK | wx.ICON_ERROR)
            self.Close()

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        user_lbl = wx.StaticText(self, label="Log in Successfull")

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Main App")
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        # Ask user to login
        dlg = LoginDialog()
        dlg.ShowModal()
        authenticated = dlg.logged_in
        dlg.Destroy()
        if not authenticated:
            wx.MessageBox('Login failed', 'Error', wx.OK | wx.ICON_ERROR)
            self.Destroy()
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Lock image - [image: 'The lock image png file']

[image][image]

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

As others have already commented, the easiest way to do this is to create a hidden TextCtrl and change it to the password widget.

The BoxSizer is very useful in these cases. I leave you a very simple example.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-


import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):        
        kwds["style"] = kwds.get("style", 0) | wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.SetSize((463, 300))
        self.txtPassword = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "", style=wx.TE_PASSWORD)
        self.txtPasswordShow = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.btnShowPassword = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Show")
        self.btnHidePassword = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Hide")

        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()

        # Same event handler:
        self.btnShowPassword.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnBtnShowHidePass)
        self.btnHidePassword.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnBtnShowHidePass)        

    def __set_properties(self):        
        self.SetTitle("frame")
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(185, 230, 255))

        # These widgets are hidden at the beginning:
        self.txtPasswordShow.Hide()
        self.btnHidePassword.Hide()        

    def __do_layout(self):

        #main default sizer:
        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        #layout sizer:
        grid_sizer_1 = wx.FlexGridSizer(1, 2, 0, 0)

        # We add all the widgets (hidden and visible) to the appropriate BoxSizer:
        grid_sizer_3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        grid_sizer_2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        grid_sizer_2.Add(self.txtPassword, 0, 0, 0)
        grid_sizer_2.Add(self.txtPasswordShow, 0, 0, 0)
        grid_sizer_1.Add(grid_sizer_2, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        
        grid_sizer_3.Add(self.btnShowPassword, 0, 0, 0)
        grid_sizer_3.Add(self.btnHidePassword, 0, 0, 0)
        grid_sizer_1.Add(grid_sizer_3, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        
        sizer_1.Add(grid_sizer_1, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 10)
        
        self.SetSizer(sizer_1)
        self.Layout()
    
    def OnBtnShowHidePass(self, event):
        # If it is visible, we hide it:
        if self.btnShowPassword.IsShown():
            self.btnShowPassword.Hide()
            self.btnHidePassword.Show()
            self.txtPassword.Hide()
            self.txtPasswordShow.Show()
            # We pass the data from one widget to another to keep it:
            self.txtPasswordShow.SetValue(self.txtPassword.GetValue())
        else:
            self.btnShowPassword.Show()
            self.btnHidePassword.Hide()
            self.txtPassword.Show()
            self.txtPasswordShow.Hide()
            self.txtPassword.SetValue(self.txtPasswordShow.GetValue())

        self.Layout()

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MainFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()
        return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Finally, I recommend using WxGlade to design your graphical interfaces in wxpython.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers make use of two TextCtrl widgets to accomplish this, but *assuming you are targeting a GTK platform*, it's sufficient to alter just the style dynamically (which GTK supports), like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import wx


class PasswordToggleDemo(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        label = wx.StaticText(self, label='Password:', size=(80, 30))
        self.pass_box = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(150, 30), style=wx.TE_PASSWORD)
        self.show_password = wx.CheckBox(self, label='show')

        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox.Add(label, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALL, 5)
        hbox.Add(self.pass_box, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALL, 5)
        hbox.Add(self.show_password, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALL, 5)

        self.SetSizer(hbox)

        self.show_password.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.on_password_checkbox)

    def on_password_checkbox(self, event):
        """Show/hide the password."""
        style = self.pass_box.GetWindowStyle()
        if self.show_password.IsChecked():
            style &= ~wx.TE_PASSWORD  # clear password style
        else:
            style |= wx.TE_PASSWORD  # set password style
        self.pass_box.SetWindowStyle(style)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    dialog = PasswordToggleDemo(None)
    dialog.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```